# Как поставить анимации в очередь

Tags: c#, silverlight

```
firstAnimation.Begin();
secondAnimation.Begin();
```

Идут две анимации, но вторая выполняется до окончания первой (мгновенно). Как их поставить в очередь?

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей удобно использовать [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742868.aspx). Возможны два варианта:

1. В XAML установить время начала (BeginTime) второй анимации на время завершения первой.
2. В C# использовать событие Completed первой анимации для начала второй.

Например

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

// ...
sb.Completed += delegate {
    // Начать вторую анимацию
};
```

Comment: <pre>
sb.Completed += ()=> {//красивее
    // Начать вторую анимацию
};
</pre>